# Text box value not updating

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a script that can calculate a refund amount the formula for working it out: total = (tax * quantity).

The total and the tax value are stored in hidden text boxes and I want the value for the refund to change when the quantity is changed my JavaScript function for this is:

```
  function refund(){
  var number = document.getElementsByName("value");
  for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) { 
      var tax = document.getElementsByName("tax")[i].value;
      var total = document.getElementsByName("total")[i].value;
      var quan = document.getElementsByName("quantity")[i].value;
      var final = +total + (+tax * +quan);
      document.getElementsByName("value")[i].value = final;

    }
}
```

and a screenshot of what it looks like is this:

[image]

So it's working in the sense that the value is correct and the text box is populated but when i update the quantity field the value is not changing. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but as JavaScript is new to me I can't spot it.

### Edit

Here is a sample of the whole table, form and JavaScript code:

```
 <table class="list" style="table-layout: auto;width: 65%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;text-align: center;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Product</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Value</td>
          <td>Refund</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
<?php foreach($missing_products as $missing){?>
  <?php $total = $missing['total'] + ($missing['tax'] * $missing['quantity']);?>
  <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="<?php echo $missing['tax']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo $missing['total']; ?>">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $missing['name']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="number" onclick="refund();" name="quantity" min="1" max="<?php echo $missing['quantity'];?>" value="<?php echo $missing['quantity'];?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="value" name="value" value=""></td>
  </tr>
<?php }?>     
    </table>

<script>
function refund(){
  var number = document.getElementsByName("value");
  for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) { 
      var tax = document.getElementsByName("tax")[i].value;
      var total = document.getElementsByName("total")[i].value;
      var quan = document.getElementsByName("quantity")[i].value;
      var refund = +total + (+tax * +quan);
      document.getElementsByName("value")[i].value = refund;

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: use `onchange` event attached to input fields to call `refund`

Comment: I have tried this but the same result, they dont update.

Comment: You sure you are not getting a console error message ? click F12 and see browser console for any errors when you change the value.

Comment: Nope none, whats frustrating is that its working it out fine, its setting the value fine and its calling the function fine the bit that isn't working is me changing the quantity it should then update the value text box accordingly but alas it is not.

Comment: @MikeAbineri Are you sure it's calling the function when you update the value ?

try to console.out the `refund` value in the method and see whether it's working fine or not.

Comment: its calling the function because the value text box is blank I then click the quantity box and the onclick event kicks in and populates the value box with the correct amount, but then if i go to change the quantity it doesnt update.

Comment: Check this out heres a before picture, then an after picture where it updates correctly and then a pic after I have changed the value:

https://imgur.com/a/2auC8fs

Comment: After you change the value, just try to click outside of that input box and see if there is any difference ?

Comment: No difference, this is the same with both onchange and onclick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188488/discussion-between-prime-and-mike-abineri).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the refund() function when the quantity changes.

Something like

`<input type = "text" id = "quantity1" name = "quantity1" oninput = "refund()">`

oninput = "refund()" is what gets the job done

Please see this code below

```
<script>
function refund(){
    //sums two numbers
    var n1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
    var n2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;

    n1 = parseInt(n1);
    n2 = parseInt(n2)

    if(!isNaN(n1) && !isNaN(n2)){
        document.getElementById('result').value = n1 + n2;
    }
}
</script>

<input type = "text" oninput = "refund()" id = "n1"> + 
<input type = "text" oninput = "refund()" id = "n2"> = 
<input id = "result">
```

there is a syntax problem with

```
var refund = +total + (+tax * +quan);
```

should be

```
var refund = total + (tax * quan);
```

Comment: I have tried changing from onchange to onclick and just tried oninput but again its not updating the value of the text box when the quantity changes.

Comment: Be sure to declare the function refund() before the input. Also, change the name of your 'final' variable. 'final' is a JavaScript keyword

Comment: Ah ok noted, I have changed it from final, and moved the script to load before the form is created, its odd because its setting the value correctly and the function is executing fine as it populates the value text box with the correct amount, it just doesnt update when the quantity changes.

Comment: I have now updated all of it to paint a more full picture

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in jsfiddle and it was kinda working.

Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3kyux1j0/

Just confirm that when you change the `Quantity` the method get called all the time or not. You can do this with a simple `Console.log()`. See the fiddle for more details.

Comment: Ah well it calls the first time but when i go to change it from then onwards it doesnt, so I can only seem to call the function once?

Comment: Now you can debug line by line. Simply you can try the console debug. If not just remove the function content and add a `console.log` and check it's getting called or not ? if yes, Then gradually add the function logic to see where it get fails. If not then there might be another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` event and accept the event in the function and can use the `target.value` to update data on the DOM.

Please find and example below

```js
function refund(e){
  console.log('e', e.target.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onchange="refund(event);" name="quantity" min="1">
```